# Almacenar en fichero texto varios objetos usando metodos

Tags: java, eclipse, objeto, java-util-scanner, filewriter

tengo un problema que no consigo hayar. Tengo la clase start y la clase persona.
en la clase start instancio 5 personas y en la clase persona tengo 3 atributos los cuales son:
nombre, apellidos, idioma. Tengo creado un metodo llamado pedir datos() que solicita medianto un scanner ingresar datos. Tengo creado File y el filewriter y si solo llamo al metodo una vez en el start "persona.pedirDatos()" todo va correctamente, el problema lo tengo cuando pongo 2 veces el metodo tal como lo tengo aqui

La clase start

```
    Persona persona1 = new Persona();
    Persona persona2 = new Persona();
    Persona persona3 = new Persona();
    Persona persona4 = new Persona();
    Persona persona5 = new Persona();
    
    persona1.pedirDatos();
    persona2.pedirDatos();
```

y en la clase Persona

```
    protected String nombre;
    protected String apellido;
    protected String idioma;
    
    //metodos propios
    public void pedirDatos() throws IOException {
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            
            File file = new File("datos.txt");
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("datos.txt");
            
            System.out.println("Nombre: ");
            nombre = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Apellido");
            apellido = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("idioma");
            idioma = scanner.nextLine();
            
            file.createNewFile();
            writer.write(nombre + "-");
            writer.write(apellido + "-");
            writer.write(idioma + "-");
            
            writer.close();
```

este es el mensaje error

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
  at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
  at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1478)
  at ACT2.Persona.pedirDatos(Persona.java:23)
  at ACT2.Start.main(Start.java:19)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que ambos `Scanner` utilizarían el mismo `InputStream` se la consola siendo un recurso que no se puede compartir entre múltiples instancias, entonces al cerrar el primer Scanner cierras el `InputStream` y el segundo Scanner no lo tendrá disponible por eso el error `java.util.NoSuchElementException`, según la documentación solo debes de tener una sola instancia de `Scanner` durante toda la vida del aplicativo. Entonces la solución seria que instancies el scanner en la clase `Start` y pases como parámetro en el constructor la instancia del scanner o que nunca cierres el recurso, te muestro un ejemplo:

```
public class Persona {
    protected String nombre;
    protected String apellido;
    protected String idioma;

    private final Scanner scanner;

    public Persona(Scanner scanner) {
        this.scanner = scanner;
    }

    public void pedirDatos() throws IOException {
        File file = new File("datos.txt");
        try(FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("datos.txt");){
            System.out.println("Nombre: ");
            nombre = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Apellido");
            apellido = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("idioma");
            idioma = scanner.nextLine();

            writer.write(nombre + "-");
            writer.write(apellido + "-");
            writer.write(idioma + "-");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);) {
            Persona persona1 = new Persona(scanner);
            Persona persona2 = new Persona(scanner);

            persona1.pedirDatos();
            persona2.pedirDatos();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Para evitar que el `FileWriter` limpie el archivo en cada escritura debes de habilitar la propiedad append a true `FileWriter("datos.txt", true)` esta hara que cuando escribas texto lo agregue sobre el que ya esta, otro cambio es que la clase `FileWriter` ya se encarga de crear el archivo si no existe entonces la clase `File` es redundante.

```
    public void pedirDatos() throws IOException {

        try(FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("datos.txt", true)){
            System.out.println("Nombre: ");
            nombre = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Apellido");
            apellido = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("idioma");
            idioma = scanner.nextLine();

            writer.write(nombre + "-");
            writer.write(apellido + "-");
            writer.write(idioma + "-");
            writer.write(idioma + "-");
            writer.write(System.lineSeparator()); // Salto de linea

        }
    }
```

Comment: Me sirvio ahora ya no me da error^^. Pero cuando me guarda el .txt solo me guarda la ultima persona que he puesto, yo tengo 5 personas y solo se me guarda el dato de la persona5. ¿Algo que deba añadir y/o cambiar?

Comment: Ya he colocado el cambio para que no te borre el texto en cada escritura, y algunas sugerencias extra.

Comment: Genial ya funciona correctamente, muchisimas gracias tu explicacion ha sido muy facil de entender ademas ^^

Comment: Me ha servido de maravilla. Muchas gracias jeje :P